# What's best strategy to combine designer and web development work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm about to work on web sites and applications. Some stylish look and feel is required so I will have a designer's work at my disposition.

However, for bad, designer person isn't any related with web at all. I think he works mostly with vectorial files.

I have general knowledge of HTML, JavaScript and jQuery. I understand the advantages of CSS and even I'm not much into it I have no problems about learning as much as needed soon. I'm open and keen about any JavaScript library. I'm also aware of the existance of DOM.

I've thought I could take care of:

- General UI
- Basic structure of the HTML document
- Navigation and user experience traits

So I'd ask designer for graphic elements, in the right dimensions according to the DOM I've got. (I'm not sure what to do about responsive to be honest, as I've never worked on that)

About audience, we're assuming users with newest versions browsers and likely to prefer interactive interfaces.

So my question is, how good can this be? And how easy from a vectorial file could it be to generate a CSS class for let's say buttons, divs, etc?

What happens when it comes to the work of a CMS like Drupal or Joomla?

Comment: Just a brief comment - you can use SVG files on the web. So long as your target audience can all be assumed to have compliant browsers, you can concentrate on aspect-ratio, rather than absolute dimensions.

Comment: what's your audience? i think the best starter is always analyzing th e audience and designing the UI and navigation. then think about design, and then about tech stuff

Comment: Well it depends on the situation, but I don't think it's that simple for a pure "designer" to do so.

Comment: Can you tell quite more about it @enhzflep I think your comment might make the answer

Comment: Plan, design, build, revise, produce? Isn't that how you build every product? Designer designs some prettyness, you learn CSS, then you know how to put prettyness on the web.

Comment: @diegoaguilar - sure. Just as you can assign a bmp/png/jpg image file to an `<img>` element's src attribute, you can also assign an svg file. This gives the obvious benefit of smaller file-size in certain cases and frees you from worrying about the dimensions. Here's a good link: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: Get the right person for the job. You don't hire a painter to paint a portrait, and vice versa, you don't hire a artist to paint your house. There are plenty of competent persons with the right skill set out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with a designer is great. Designers have plenty of time to focus on the important things like typefaces and being stylish. They make the hardest choices for you. Assuming they don't go nuts and create a design that is inflexible, or way out of your league, making most designs with css is very possible. Any major issues can be fixed with a compromise in design. There are infinite ways to make things look cool. Choose one you are capable of and everyone will win.

1. learn html
2. learn css
3. learn @media rules and their uses - your going to need to start with small screens and change it as screens get larger
4. strategize content with client and keep it to the point - write ALL of the html first - this will enlighten you to what you are really making
5. loosely style the html into manageable blocks - don't use bootstrap or any other crutches unless you already know them by heart
6. further mold the styles to work on all devices mobile first - might use some javascript for user interaction
7. user testing - is it intuitive and easy to navigate?
8. have the designer take your outline and decorate it like a cake in the various iterations - photoshop is for editing photos - pagemaker and illustrator are for laying out pages - have them stick to 2 font faces and a designated set of colors and textures to be signed off by client before moving on - keep an eye on them
9. apply their look with css - if you can - use a preprocessor - sass is awesome
10. port to a CMS such as WordPress etc by building a custom theme - you'll need some php or to learn about javascript templating

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about last two points. How can sass help me explode the designer's work and are there any rules for porting current css's and html specs to a custom theme?

Comment: SASS is a both a syntax and a preprocessor. It lets you write CSS in a more versatile syntax. So, you and your designer can decide on your super awesome oranges and you can use variables like $my-color --- across the css so you can keep things clear, and maybe change that color with one word in the future. It also lets you nest and use mixins which can be great for @media rule break points. Then SASS takes that .scss syntax and compresses it and spits it out to a small .css file to serve to the web. You will have more control if you form reusable chunks of css and work with variables.

Comment: If you plan on using a CMS, (you think the client would benefit) then you should plan on those things as reusable blocks. - blog entries, products - gallery - etc. Take a wide variety of these and just repeat them in html at first to style around. Make some titles really long - so you can see what will happen in scenarios like that. Is the line-height ok if it breaks to the next line? Later - you can populate the loops of products, etc with your CMS - But basic html and css should be done long before this. I would watch Chris Coyier's WordPress tutorial on Lynda.com when you get to that point.